# HttpWebRequest does not load content when 401 happend but browser does

Tags: c#, http, browser, status, httpwebresponse

I have the following situation. I am calling some web api to login to a certain server. The call looks like that:
 webhost/login?username=email@domain.com&password=alin
The return is always an xml like:

```
<response>
 <error>invalid user</error>
</response>
```

or

```
<response>
 <token>XXXXXXX</token>
</response>
```

So, if I call this api with the wrong credentials, the page return with a 401 http status, and then at this line

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

it raise an error and it jumps in catch block. (of course) The thing is, the next line

```
stream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

never get to happen so I will never get to read the returned xml , including the error message inside it. Still, if i just paste the link in browser, the page and teh xml gets loaded

Why does the browser loads the xml and my response component does not. by the way , i am doing this in C#

Thanks

```
Stream stream = null;
try 
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(finalURL);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    stream = response.GetResponseStream();
}  
catch(Exception ex)
{
    string x = ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get content of response with StatusCode 401](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037687/get-content-of-response-with-statuscode-401)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you're not *trying* to look at the response.

If you catch a *specific* exception (as you should - catching `Exception` is a bad idea in most cases) you could get at the response data:

```
catch (WebException e)
{
    WebResponse response = e.Response;
    // TODO: Check whether the status code is one you can handle
    // Get the data from here...
}
```

Note that you should have a `using` statement for your `HttpWebResponse` in the non-failure condition too, otherwise you'll end up leaving resources open.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (ex is WebException)
{
    var webException = ex as WebException;
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)webException.Response;

    switch (response.StatusCode)
     {
           case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:

               var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
              break;

       }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find out the user agent string of your browser and then set the user agent string on your WebRequest to match. Many sites serve variant content/markup/styles/scripts based on the UA.

For `HttpWebRequest`, you can set the UA by the UserAgent property.

See if this helps.